# Change of directory with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, centos

Hello then I state that something very strange happens to me, which had never happened to me.
So I have a node.js application that runs perfectly on a centos server! Once the application has been loaded on the server, boot with node server.js and everything is working on perfection! As a reboot I set a cron to start the server node with this syntax:

`**@reboot node /var/www/html/app/main.js**`

the problem is that when I restart the machine the cron starts correctly node.js but when I have to do the change of directory below I have this error:

> **Node.js Code:**
>
> process.chdir('./Model');

**Directory Tree:**

/var/www/html/app

/var/www/html/app/main.js

/var/www/html/app/Model

**Error:**
**ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_chdir**

Comment: What's the error? Can you please update the question including the error?

Comment: @yaswanth I have add  error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is current working directory of your process? Try console.log(`Starting directory: ${process.cwd()}`); to see if it is /var/www/html/app.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38951/what-is-the-working-directory-when-cron-executes-a-job).

Just adding a node command in cron won't work. You need to do `cd into your project root dir` and execute `node` command.